# Create a DF after registering a previous DF in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am a new developer at Spark Scala and I want to ask you about my problem.

I have two huge dataframes, my second dataframe is computed from the first dataframe (it contains a distinct column from the first one).

To optimize my code, I thought about this approach :

- Register my first dataframe as a .csv file in HDFS
- And then simply read this .csv file to calculate the second dataframe.

So, it wrote this :

```
//val temp1 is my first DF
writeAsTextFileAndMerge("result1.csv", "/user/result", temp1, spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

val temp2 = spark.read.options(Map("header" -> "true", "delimiter" -> ";"))
      .csv("/user/result/result1.csv").select("ID").distinct

    writeAsTextFileAndMerge("result2.csv", "/user/result",
      temp2, spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
```

And this is my save function :

```
def writeAsTextFileAndMerge(fileName: String, outputPath: String, df: DataFrame, conf: Configuration) {
    val sourceFile = WorkingDirectory
    df.write.options(Map("header" -> "true", "delimiter" -> ";")).mode("overwrite").csv(sourceFile)
    merge(fileName, sourceFile, outputPath, conf)
  }

  def merge(fileName: String, srcPath: String, dstPath: String, conf: Configuration) {
    val hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf)
    val destinationPath = new Path(dstPath)
    if (!hdfs.exists(destinationPath))
      hdfs.mkdirs(destinationPath)
    FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath + "/" + fileName),
      true, conf, null)
  }
```

It seems "logical" to me but I got errors doing this. I guess it's not possible for Spark to "wait" until registering my first DF in HDFS and AFTER read this new file (or maybe I have some errors on my save function ?).

Here is the exception that I got :

```
19/02/16 17:27:56 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Can you help me to fix this please ?

Comment: can you share the exceptions that are emitted?

Comment: i just got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException... It saids : 
ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the merge - Spark is not aware and thus not synchronized with all the HDFS operations you are making.

The good news is that you don't need to do that. just do df.write and then create a new dataframe with the read (spark will read all the parts into a single df)

i.e. the following would work just fine

```
temp1.write.options(Map("header" -> "true", "delimiter" -> ";")).mode("overwrite").csv("/user/result/result1.csv")
val temp2 = spark.read.options(Map("header" -> "true", "delimiter" -> ";"))
      .csv("/user/result/result1.csv").select("ID").distinct
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand well. How can you read an entire repository and all its parts ? By using the same .csv() function ?

Comment: When multiple workers write a "file" you actually get a directory with parts. When you spark gets a read command pointing to the parent directory it reads all the parts (by the way it worked the same in Hadoop map/reduce)